# UINavigationBar not showing

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a swift project that is programmatic and segues from a mapview to another view.  After the segue the navigation bar is not present.  Since the files were copied over from an earlier project where this doesn't happen I'm perplexed.  It should be very straight forward.

In AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let homeViewController = MapViewController()

    self.navigationController = UINavigationController()
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
    navigationController?.viewControllers = [homeViewController]
    self.window!.rootViewController = navigationController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 17)!]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = attributes

    return true
}
```

And the segue code called in the MapViewController:

```
    let storeViewController = ViewController()
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
    appDelegate.navigationController?.pushViewController(storeViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Why you segue from  appDelegate

Comment: The segue code is in the mapviewcontroller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to embedded MapViewController in `UINavigationController` and Push `ViewControllers` as needed

to hide use  `self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false`

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

            // Override point for customization after application launch.
            window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

            let homeViewController = MapViewController()
            let navController  = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeViewController)

            self.window!.rootViewController = navController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

            let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 17)!]
            UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = attributes

        return true
    }
```

and in `MapViewController`

To navigate:

```
    let storeViewController = ViewController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(storeViewController, animated: true)

    //if you want to hide or show navigation
   //self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false // true
```

Comment: I usually do the embedding via storyboard, so I'm unclear how it is working in the code example you gave.  In the UINavigationController constructor you are passing a param for rootViewController that is homeViewController, but then below your setting self.window!.rootViewController = navController.  Can you provide some explanation?

Comment: rootViewController of UINavigationController is First viewController in the Stack